# Accessing contents from a symbolic link created in htdocs

Tags: apache, webserver, htdocs

We have set up apache server and created a symbolic to logs folder.

**Problem:**
When we try access the logs using http:/server:port/logs the logs appear properly in browser. However when we are using big ip url that is *http:/bigipurl/logs* url rewrites as *http:/bigipurl:port/logs* and the page doesnt get displayed.

**Observation:**
If we use *http:/bigipurl/logs/* logs are getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, Added directoryslash off under the respective directory section in httpd.conf file.